# How to subset a list using map?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following list:

```
list(list(list(name = 'John'), list(name=c("Jack", "Kate"))))
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]]$name
[1] "John"


[[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[2]]$name
[1] "Jack" "Kate"
```

and I would like to extract a list of `name` only. I know I can use

```
list(list(list(name = 'John'), list(name=c("Jack", "Kate"))))%>% map(list(1, 'name'))
```

to extract name from the first element. But how do I extract `name` from every element to get this:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] "John"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Jack" "Kate"
```

**UPDATE**: I just realized I could use `flatten()`, but how would I do it using  map with proper indexing?

Comment: What output do you want? `x %>% flatten() %>% flatten()` or `x %>% pluck(1) %>% map('name')`, maybe

Comment: @alistaire I updated my response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `modify_depth`, `pluck`, and `flatten` here, all functions from `purrr`

```
your_list <- list(list(list(name = 'John'), list(name=c("Jack", "Kate"))))

library(purrr)
modify_depth(your_list, .depth = 2, .f = pluck, "name") %>% 
 flatten()
#[[1]]
#[1] "John"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Jack" "Kate"
```

Comment: Didn't know about `pluck` but your code gives me an error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: My bad I was using `rvest::pluck`. This namespace conflict is a bit of unexpected tho, I thought they both belonged to the tidyverse...

Comment: They do. I'm not clear on why Hadley has allowed these conflicts to occur within his packages.

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist <- list(list(list(name = 'John'), list(name=c("Jack", "Kate"))))

library(purrr)

map(mylist[[1]], ~ .[[1]]) %>% 
  flatten_chr()

# [1] "John" "Jack" "Kate"
```

I assumed that you wanted to return a vector of names, as opposed to another list.

EDIT: Never mind you wanted to keep it as a list.